# Php unit test 401

Tags: php, unit-testing

When I try to test my api with the following code:

```
$client = new Client();
        $res = $client->request('POST', $this->url.'/api/v1/school/1', [
            'form_params' => [
                'currentUserId' => 1
            ]
        ]); //line 22

        $obj = json_decode($res->getBody());
        $result = $obj->{'result'}->{'message'};
        $this->assertEquals('Error', $result);
```

It is not going further then line 22 (see comment). When I post to the same url in postman the result is (with status code 401):

```
{
  "result": {
    "message": "Error",
    "school": "Error show school"
  }
}
```

But why is it not going further in my unit test? when I make 200 as response it is going further!

Comment: Can you please place `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the start of your script and post any errors or warnings. Generally a good idea to have error reporting on during tests.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment your question so I will need to ask in my answer. What kind of error do you receive in line 22 or why does the script break? Do you have enabled error-reporting and/or checked the log-files?

Try to dump `$res` if there is no error/exception thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer! You have to add:

```
['http_errors' => false]
```

Method now:

```
$client = new Client();
        $res = $client->request('POST', $this->url.'/api/v1/school/1',['http_errors' => false], [
            'form_params' => [
                'currentUserId' => 1
            ]
        ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Although Jamie's answer seems to work but there is a very small detail you should be careful of. If you use :

```
$client = new Client();
$res = $client->request('POST', $this->url.'/api/v1/school/1',['http_errors' => false], [
       'form_params' => ['currentUserId' => 1]
       ]);
```

as in Jamie's answer, you will always get 200 status code, even if you provide wrong credentials and you was supposed to get 401, that's why this code will never block your process but that doesn't mean your motive to check against 401 status is fulfilled. 
If you really wanna check if it returns 401 by phpunit, you should use it like this:

```
$client = new Client();
$res = $client->request('POST', $this->url.'/api/v1/school/1',[
       'http_errors' => false,
       'form_params' => ['currentUserId' => 1]
       ]);
$status = $response->getStatusCode();
$this->assertEquals(401,$status);
```

This will result OK as it will actually match returned code against 401.

*I hope it's clear and helps*